# Prove $P \lor (P \land Q) \equiv P$ without using a truth table

Tags: propositional-calculus

I don't know how to solve the question above without using a truth table. If anyone could help me, that would be great! The method used should be used something like LHS and RHS.

Comment: You have to use [Logical equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf).

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove the equivalence showing: *(i)* $[P \lor (P \land Q)] \to P$ and *(ii)* $P \to [P \lor (P \land Q)]$.

Comment: *(ii)* is trivial, using [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction).

Comment: For (i), you have to use [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Answer (score 2):

You use $\phi\rightarrow \phi\lor\psi$ (disjunction introduction) and $\phi\land\psi\rightarrow\phi$ (conjunction elimination) together with the distsributive law and idempotence:

$$\begin{align}
P\lor(P\land Q)
&\leftrightarrow (P\lor P)\land(P\lor Q) & \text{Distributive law}\\
&\leftrightarrow P\land (P\lor Q)&\text{Idempotence}\\
&\rightarrow P &{\phi\land\psi\rightarrow\phi}\\
&\rightarrow P\lor (P\land Q) & \phi\rightarrow\phi\lor\psi
\end{align}$$

Then of course you use that $\phi\rightarrow\psi\rightarrow\phi$ means that $\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 cases:

1. $\mathcal{P}$ is false $\Leftrightarrow (\mathcal{P} \wedge\mathcal{Q})$ is false $\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{P}\vee (\mathcal{P} \wedge\mathcal{Q})$ is false.
2. $\mathcal{P}$ is true $\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{P}\vee (\mathcal{P} \wedge\mathcal{Q})$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

$$P\land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$(P \lor \bot) \land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$P \lor (\bot \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Annihilation)}$$

$$P \lor \bot \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$P$$